# LogIn Logs Checking

Tags: ssh, logs, login

I just want to be sure about some log entries. When I run the command for checking successful login attempts?

```
utmpdump /var/log/wtmp
```

It shows just '4' or '5' in terminal column of the file, and 'LOGIN' in the user column?

More weird users like 'runlevel' , 'reboot'.

Does anyone have any idea what's this all about?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `last` command:

```
last -20
```

shows the last 20 successful logins.

Also shown are times of last reboot (instead of username).